# How to assign a same value to entity using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities, ado.net-entity-data-model

Example :

```
     EmpID GroupID  Amount GroupCode
      001   G01      1000  GC00001
      001   G02      2000  GC00002
```

In my List i getting the EmployeeEmployee (E001,E001).Here how can i set the each Emplid to groupCodeusing LINQ.

Details has (E001,E002)

```
Foreach(Employee empty in Details)
 {
    GroupDetails GD=a.GroupDetails(empty.EmppID) //as above data will have above example
    Now GD has GC00001,GC00002
 }
```

How can we go do?

Comment: I'm not sure quite what the problem is, can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is something like:

```
foreach (var employee in details)
{
    var groupCodes = from item in a
                     where item.EmpID == employee.EmpID
                     select item.GroupCode;

    // use groupCodes here...
}
```